# Trigger copy data from table2 when only one data in table1 inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerPickup
    ON dbo.Pickup
    AFTER INSERT 
    AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.Pickup( PickupProxy,PickupHispanic,EthnCode,CategCode,AgencyID)
         SELECT
              Clients.ClientProxy, Clients.Hispanic, Clients.EthnCode, Clients.CategCode,Clients.AgencyID
         FROM
             dbo.Clients,Pickup
             where   Pickup.ClientID =Clients.ClientID
    END
```

however if i submit insert statement like this. It supposed to pull data from client table and insert in in the same row in which i insert ID and date, however it  creates new records and put  data in them.

```
INSERT INTO Pickup (ClientID, PickupDate)
VALUES (13144, '2010-11-20');
```

it is not  copping any data from clients table it just insert empty rows
[image: how does select * from pickup looks like] 
Any Ideas what is going on and where is my mistake in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [INSTEAD OF INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) trigger or AFTER trigger with UPDATE statements

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerPickup ON dbo.Pickup
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.Pickup( PickupDate,
                    PickupProxy, PickupHispanic, EthnCode, CategCode, AgencyID)
  SELECT i.PickupDate, 
         c.ClientProxy, c.Hispanic, c.EthnCode, c.CategCode, c.AgencyID
  FROM dbo.Clients c JOIN inserted i ON i.ClientID = c.ClientID
END
```

AFTER TRIGGER

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerPickup ON dbo.Pickup
FOR INSERT
AS BEGIN
  UPDATE p
  SET p.PickupProxy = c.ClientProxy,
      p.PickupHispanic = c.PickupHispanic,
      p.EthnCode = c.EthnCode,
      p.CategCode = c.CategCode,
      p.AgencyID = c.AgencyID
  FROM inserted i JOIN dbo.Clients c ON i.ClientID = c.ClientID
                  JOIN dbo.Pickup p ON i.PickupID = p.PickupID
END
```

Comment: can I ask you some thing about this trigger in chat?

Comment: mojesh obyasnit  wot etu liniu ? FROM dbo.Clients c JOIN inserted i ON i.ClientID = c.ClientID

Comment: can you look this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237583/mssql-trigger-update-data-in-to-table-but-should-update-data-only-when-customer#comment21484538_15237583