# SQL Server trigger update data in to table but should update data only when customer doing insert or update one client

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Right now trigger looks like this and it works partly

My trigger looks like this

```
   ALTER  trigger [dbo].[tr_EligebilityCheck]
on [dbo].[Clients]
 for INSERT,update
as 

BEGIN
UPDATE Clients 
SET 
StatusID = 5
WHERE 
ClientID IN (Select ClientID
            from Clients c 
            join inserted --ADD THIS JOIN
            on inserted.ClientID = c.ClientID
            join IncomeEligibility i 
            on c.HshldSize = i.HshldSize
            where StatusID in (1,2) 
            and  WIC = 0
            and (c.CategCode = 'SR' 
                and ((MonthlyYearly = 'month' and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorMo) 
                or (c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorYr and MonthlyYearly ='year'))
                and DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,GETDATE()) < 60)
            or
                (c.CategCode = 'CH' 
                and ((MonthlyYearly = 'month' and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.WomanChildMo) 
    or (c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.WomanChildYr and MonthlyYearly ='year'))
                and DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,GETDATE()) > 6))

update Clients
set StatusID = 4 
where WIC =1
from Clients --ADD THIS FROM STATEMENT
join inserted --ADD THIS JOIN
on inserted.ClientID = Clients.ClientID

END
```

when I inset client with CategCode = 'SR' it check only DOB and fire if client is younger than 60 but if clients is older it did not check this

```
and ((MonthlyYearly = 'month' and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorMo) 
                    or (c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorYr and MonthlyYearly ='year'))
```

If I insert client with CategCode = 'CH' it check Income but did not check DOB.

Comment: Inserted table? The problem is i don't understand how to wright it i can do it for insert or after insert  but  do not understand how to do it for `INSTEAD OF INSERT`.

Comment: Maybe start with something simpler... also, can you explain WHY you think this needs to be an INSTEAD OF trigger? And what your final update is attempting to do - are you trying to update every row in the table?

Comment: I think I need it `INSTEAD OF`  because if it is just FOR Insert, Update it change exist  data in DB  which cannot be changed. Example is person applied for program with one requirements for household and he is in program them requirements changed  but  he still should be in program. if I use `FOR INSERT, UPDATE` it  will set  his status a s not eligible. Because of that  I need to check client  data before it inserted into table so it  will not change exist records in DB. As I understand `INSTEAD OF INSERT` it is the same function as `BEFORE UPDATE` which used in `Oracle `.

Comment: I am trying to update only that record which going to be inserted or updated. But do not modifying any exist  data in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have a proper reference to a primary key, I don't see why you would need an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. It doesn't seem like there is any situation in which you'd prevent an insert or update, correct? You just want to make sure of the value of StatusID. There's no reason that has to be done before the update.

I believe the reason you're getting too many rows updated is that you're not limiting the trigger to only those rows in the `inserted` table. Try adding a join to your trigger, like so:

```
ALTER  trigger [dbo].[tr_EligebilityCheck]
on [dbo].[Clients]
 for INSERT,update
as 

BEGIN
UPDATE Clients 
SET 
StatusID = 5
WHERE 
ClientID IN (Select ClientID
            from Clients c 
            join inserted --ADD THIS JOIN
            on inserted.ClientID = c.ClientID
            join IncomeEligibility i 
            on c.HshldSize = i.HshldSize
            where StatusID in (1,2) 
            and  WIC = 0
            and (c.CategCode = 'SR' 
                and ((MonthlyYearly = 'month' and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorMo) 
                or (c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorYr and MonthlyYearly ='year'))
                and DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,GETDATE()) < 60)
            or
                (c.CategCode = 'CH' 
                and ((MonthlyYearly = 'month' and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.WomanChildMo) 
    or (c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.WomanChildYr and MonthlyYearly ='year'))
                and DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,GETDATE()) > 6))

update Clients
set StatusID = 4 
where WIC =1
from Clients --ADD THIS FROM STATEMENT
join inserted --ADD THIS JOIN
on inserted.ClientID = Clients.ClientID

END
```

If you do want to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, a few pointers on that: `INSTEAD OF` is *not* the same thing as `BEFORE UPDATE`. `BEFORE UPDATE` alters the `inserted` table and then proceeds with the update. `INSTEAD OF` cancels the insert or update entirely, which means you need to explicitly re-write it. I have an example below.

Also, if you want to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, you'll either need separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers, or you'll need to write your query as a `MERGE` statement. I'll use `INSERT` in my example below:

```
ALTER  trigger [dbo].[tr_EligebilityCheck]
on [dbo].[Clients]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
as 

BEGIN

--First, set StatusID in the inserted table
UPDATE inserted
SET 
StatusID = 5
WHERE 
ClientID IN (Select ClientID
            from Clients c 
            join IncomeEligibility i 
            on c.HshldSize = i.HshldSize
            where StatusID in (1,2) 
            and  WIC = 0
            and (c.CategCode = 'SR' 
                and ((MonthlyYearly = 'month' and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorMo) 
                or (c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorYr and MonthlyYearly ='year'))
                and DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,GETDATE()) < 60)
            or
                (c.CategCode = 'CH' 
                and ((MonthlyYearly = 'month' and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.WomanChildMo) 
    or (c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.WomanChildYr and MonthlyYearly ='year'))
                and DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,GETDATE()) > 6));

update inserted
set StatusID = 4 
where WIC =1;

--Once the inserted table looks right, proceed with the insert
--You need to explicitly write an insert statement, or nothing will happen
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Clients]
  <column_list>
SELECT <column_list>
FROM inserted;
```

Comment: First variant works but it check only DOB howewer skipinng `and ((MonthlyYearly = 'month' and c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorMo) or (c.AnnualHshldIncome >= i.SeniorYr and MonthlyYearly ='year'))` part and I don't understand why

Comment: and in second or this part doesn't work `and DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,GETDATE()) > 6));` do you see any problem there way it doesn't work?

Comment: So, same problem you were having before. I wasn't sure about this, which is why I didn't attempt to alter your `where` clauses. It's hard to say without some sample data to practice on. There's got to be an issue _somewhere_ in your `where` clauses, but I'm not sure where it is. My first guess, though, would be that it has something to do with the arrangement of the parenthesis.